# How to verify email confirmation token generated by web service in web site

Tags: .net-4.5, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using .NET 4.5 with a MVC5 5.2.2 web site and a Web API 2.2 service. The web site is using Identity 2.0, and I'm using MachineKey as a data protection provider. In the web site, I'm able to create new users, generate an email confirmation token and then verify that token when it comes back.

In the web service, I need to follow the same process - create a new user, generate email confirmation token and email that token to the new user. The user should then be able to visit the site, confirm the email address and finish creating the account. The problem I'm having is the email confirmation tokens generated by the web service can't be verified by the web site.

Both the service and the site are on the same machine. I can also duplicate this on my local machine in Visual Studio. My first guess was the machine keys weren't the same, but changing both sites to use the same hasn't worked. I've tried and confirmed:

- Both sites have `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>` in the `<system.web>` section.
- I've tried `<machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework45"/>` in both sites.
- I've tried generating machine keys - using `decryption=AES` and `validation=SHA1` - with and without setting compatibilityMode.
- Per https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2439, I tried capturing the data protection provider and using that instead of MachineKey.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So my first lesson from yesterday is that it is best to play Russian roulette with as few bullets in the chamber as possible. Otherwise you end up with a sore foot...as well as a sore forehead.

My problem ended up being that while I knew the confirmation tokens were being url encoded correctly from the site since I was using `UrlHelper`, I was forgetting the service was not using `UrlHelper` which mean **those** tokens were **not** being encoded correctly. After fixing that, I was able to figure out the `machinekey` settings.

For anyone who finds this, if you need to share Identity 2.0 tokens between different sites, I can confirm that you need a common `machinekey` set in your web.config for each site. I wasn't able to figure out if a common `machinekey` can be configured in IIS Express, so I ended up putting the keys in the web.config in source control then using the config transforms to remove them to make sure they aren't included when the site is published. In production, I'm going to use IIS to set these keys for the default web site so they are shared across both sites.